# Access higher TTYs and the role of getty

Tags: tty, getty

I have a few dark areas when trying to understands TTYs.

- On my system, I have `/dev/tty[1-63]`. Is `udev` creating these character devices? And how can I access them (like tty2 can be accessed with Ctrl+Alt+F2)? How can I access `/dev/tty40` for example?
- As I understand, when I access `/dev/tty1`, `agetty` is called, which then calls `login`. What really is the role of `agetty` outside of calling `login`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [virtual consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), known in Linux as *virtual terminals* (VT). There is a single hardware console (a single screen and a single keyboard), but Linux pretends that there are multiple ones (as many as 63). At a given point in time, a single VT is *active*; keyboard input is routed to that console and the screen shows what that console displays.

You can use the command [`chvt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chvt.1.html) to switch between VT (you need to have direct access to the current virtual console, which you won't have if logged remotely or running under X). You can also use keybindings set with the keymap loaded by `loadkeys` or by the X server. By default, outside X, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> switches to console number *n* and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> switches to console number *n*+12; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> switch to the previous/next console.

A console needs to be *allocated* in order to switch to it. You can use [`openvt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/openvt.1.html) to allocate a console (this requires root) and [`deallocvt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/deallocvt.1.html) to deallocate one.

The program [getty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_(Unix)) is not directly related to virtual consoles, in particular it has nothing to do with VT allocation. The role of getty is to prepare the console (set up serial port parameters, possibly blank the screen, display a welcome message, etc.) and call `login`, then wait for the login session to terminate and repeat. In a nutshell, the role of getty is to call `login` in a loop.

You don't have to run getty to use a console. For example, you can start any program on a console with `openvt`. You can start an X server on a new console with `startx`.

Comment: Fantastic answer as always Gilles, thank you for the illumination.